Apache NIFI Invoke HTTP use original request as response upon failure
I am using NIFI invokeHTTP processor and my requirement is as below:

Use GenerateFlowFile processor to generate Post body of API request
Use InvokeHTTP processor to call POST API using step request body
If invokeHTTP return success response  then pass  response data to step 4
If invokeHTTP return failure response then pass response of step 1 to step 4
Process response data

I can't use attribute to store response data as it's size is large
Below is screenshot of sample flow:

Currently i am not able to pass data from step 1 when API fails. And original relation called only if response status is 200.
